# Correct Condition syntax for SelectOutput5 in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

In AnyLogic I have a Source producing the agent "Part" in cyan, blue, red and lime. That works fine.
I have a selectOutput5 to sort out the colors.
[Model Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4XgH.png)
Condition 1:  agent.color == cyan; (for example)
All other conditions similar, but all the "Parts" spit out the bottom at 5

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ0DS.png)

I'm guessing the condition statement isn't horrible, the software reads each one and passes to the next.  Maybe the software laughs and moves on, but I'm new, very new to AnyLogic and Java.
AnyHelp is needed.
Thanks

I made several attempts.

UPDATE***********Not sure this is the place to put this*************

Thanks, I tried it.  I got an error of "Exception during discrete event execution:
NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException"

So in order to use the Traceln I changed the conditions to .2 each (default) to get flow.  Using the "my color is" statement gave "my color is java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]"

I then changed "agent.color" to "Part.color" (Part is the name of the agent created at the source).  This gives an interesting error, "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Part.color".

The Source makes an agent named "Part".  This agent has a parameter of "color" of Color type.  On exit each "Part" is made 1 of 4 colors in an If-Else-Then statement. Then another agent named "Part" and another color. So the "Part" color changes.  On the screen the "Part"s move as a color that was assigned.  But when the condition examines "agent.color" there is an error, and when it examines "Part.color" there is an error.
Still needing help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected behavior SelectOutput block in AnyLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821364/unexpected-behavior-selectoutput-block-in-anylogic)

Answer (score 0):

This only works if you have a field `color` of type  `Color` in your agent. Also, avoid the `;` at the end and use `.equals` instead of `==`

So

`agent.color.equals(Color.red)`

Agents will check each condition from 1 to 4 sequentially and exit as soon as the first is met. Else, they take the 5th exit (as in your case).

PS: Learn to use the `traceln(...)` command to print what happens, for example what your agents colors are: `traceln("my color is "+agent.color)`